# Several local and remote git repositories with Netbeans

Tags: java, git, github, netbeans, repository

I have set up a local git repository and pushed my projects in Netbeans to my remote git repository.

My intention is to create other projects in Netbeans and another local git repository in a folder on my PC and connect the new projects with this repository.

For example, I would like to add separate "NetBeansProjects2" to Netbeans IDE.

[image]

For this purpose, I have tried to use GitHub for Windows but could not "attach" the new project in Netbeans to the new local repository. I have also created another remote git repository but it just cloned all my  existing projects in Netbeans.

All tutorials I found have only one project in Netbeans as an example. When you have one to one situation, the steps are clear.

My question is how to set up several local git repositories linking to different remote git repositories and have them in Netbeans?

I am currently using Netbeans 8.2, Windows 10 and GitHub.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you have formulated a very confusing question but i think i got the grasp of the situation.
git repositories are standalone, i mean for every folder you can have a git repository, just run `git init` in that folder. you can initialize repositories under a folder of another repository:

```
/myMainRepo/
---.git
---otherProject/
-------.git
```

**repository info is stored in a folder named .git if this folder is present it means here exists a git repository**

just bear in mind that you have to add a .gitignore to determine what goes in every repository.

as for remote repositories you have to manage them yourself. just add them using the command:

```
git remote add 'name' 'url'
```

git will look for remote named origin, and a branch named master to be tracked by default.

you can add more remotes to have several repositories.

```
git remote add anotherOrign http://mygit
```

then netbeans will be able to list the existing remotes and you will decide where to push.

also you can do it using git:

```
git push anotherOrigin master -u
```

using -u tells git to track master at anotherOrigin, this way you don't need to tell git the names of remote and branch.

Comment: Currently, I have only one git folder for all projects in Netbeans. In future, I would like to have another common git folder for five new projects linking to a new remote repository.

Comment: I am sorry if it looks confusing, I am trying to find out how to add another local repository to Netbeans to have it listed in Git Repository Browser.

Comment: it seems you are confusing git repositories with netbeans project, if you have several netbeans projects open in editor they will be listed in Git Repository Browser, there is no need to add them to netbeans. also if you want to have a parent project and several child projects you can achieve this using maven, this way netbeans will show a parent project and you will be able to open child projects from there.

Comment: seeing at the image in your question seems to me that you have a git repository in your NetbeansProjects folder, that why it is displayed like that. just go to the root of your projects, and init a repository there, if it is a netbeans project it will be listed